# acr alternative in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid

We have different login scenarios.

1. Using basic login with username and password
2. Using mobile phone number to login
3. Using X509 certificate to login

`acr` is not exists in Keycloak. Currently I can create multiple realm for each of login type or define different flow for each client. But these are not efficient ways. How can I achieve this with Keylcoak?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your realm authentication flows and add execution (IMHO the best option is a script), which will set `acr` claim value based on used auth method. Of course some scripting skills and Keycloak knowledge is required.

Comment: thanks for your response. I think so. But. I could not find any related documentation about that. For example if I use script then I have to redirect the user to the different login page based on the `acr` value. When I do this the process should start from beginning. For example user wants to login with X509 certificate in this case I should redirect the user to the page where browser can request the certificate from user. `acr` is the simplest requirement in openid so  I would like to know why keycloak has not ths simple feature

Comment: @sakit everything should be handled by used login flow - single flow can cover all login options - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_authentication-flows code own conditions (e.g. on `acr` get parameter if you really want that) and design flow, which will fit your need. Please, be precise in the question next time - it really looks like your are missing `acr` claim in the token, but it's absolutely different - you want to to implement login options

Comment: I am so sorry. It seems that I misexplained the requirement. Previously I used Gluu. With Gluu we send `acr` when we redirect the user to login page. And flow decided which `login` page represent to the user. But with keycloack this process is different. Or I misunderstood the whole process